# SQL Server : execute a few different query statements in parallel

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing

Let's consider one simple query:

```
Select top 10 * 
from dbo.sometable
```

I want to run this query on a few different linked databases with the same structure but different data and return a unioned result.

This query works pretty good (Texec), but network data transmission takes a more time (Tnetwork). When I do it for 5 queries - it takes:

```
Texec  + 4 * (Tnetwork + Texec)
```

Is it possible to run each of them in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to execute a few statements parallel. In order to optimize this, I did changes on the backend:

```
var list = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
var serverIds = await _systemErrorRepository.GetAllServerIds();
Parallel.ForEach(serverIds, t =>
{
    var resultFromServer = _someRepository.GetDataOnServer<T>(t);
    AddRange(list, resultFromPod);
});
```

Also I've created a method for AddRange to ConcurentBag:

```
public static void AddRange<T>(ConcurrentBag<T> source, IEnumerable<T> toAdd)
{
    foreach (var element in toAdd)
    {
        source.Add(element);
    }
}
```